# Bitnami Helm Cassandra -- Unable to connectwith cqlsh [remotely]

Tags: cassandra, bitnami

I am not able to connect remote cassandra cluster which is built using bitnami helm chart and self signed cert. Below error.

FYI.. i have enabled ssl cqlschrc as below

[ssl]

```
; certfile = ~/keys/cassandra.cert
; Optional - true by default

validate = flase
; To be provided when require_client_auth=true
userkey = ~/key.pem
; To be provided when require_client_auth=true
usercert = ~/cert.pem
```

## ======
error below

cqlsh --ssl -u cassandra -p 123@123 10.11.xxxx.230 9042
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.11.xxxx.230:9042': IOError(2, 'No such file or directory')})

Comment: Also FYI,. my python code works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download certificate from your secrets (not Key) and name it as cert.pem
2. Install cqlsh with snap (https://snapcraft.io/install/cqlsh/ubuntu)
3. create cqlshrc under /root/snap/cqlsh/220/.cassandra with below values

root@nswamy4:~# cat /root/snap/cqlsh/220/.cassandra/cqlshrc

```
[ssl]
version = SSLv23
validate = false
certfile = /mnt/c/Users/nswamy/wsl_ubuntu/bitnami_cassandra/certs/cert.pem
```

Connect as below

cqlsh 10.11.xxx.xxx 9042 --ssl -u cassandra -p 123456

You shoudl see cassandra prompt

Comment: This is also solution for https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/12931